# ansible group_vars adjacent to inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

On ansible 2.1.1.0

given a structure as so

```
.
|-- inventories
|   `-- env
|       |-- group_vars
|       |   `-- someconfig
|       `-- hosts.ini
`-- main.yml
```

group_vars as

```
---
myconfig: somevalue
```

hosts.ini as

```
localhost

[env]
localhost
```

main.yml as

```
---
 - hosts: env
   user: someuser
   tasks:
    - debug: msg="loaded {{ myconfig }}"
```

On running

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/env/hosts.ini main.yml
```

Why isn't myconfig loaded ?

From [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16956) and [this link](http://www.geedew.com/setting-up-ansible-for-multiple-environment-deployments/) it seems that this is the recommended structure. 
So why does not the play load the group_vars adjacent from the specified inventory file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration files in the `group_vars` directory must match the group name defined in the inventory file.

In your case you either have to create a group called `someconfig` or rename that particular file to a name of one of your groups, for example `env`.